# Zephyr OS boot and flash

Tags: flash, operating-system, boot, hardware, zephyr-rtos

I tried to flash my application to Carbon 96 board (successfully).
Booting guide created bin and elf files but not image file.
How do i make a boot able file ? 
What are the required files to flash ? 
Is there any boot image file for zephyr?
Can I get explanation about flashing and booting Zephyr OS ?

Answer (score 0):

The `zephyr.bin` file is the bootable image file; it's the only file required to flash. The `zephyr.elf` file contains extra debugging information you would need to run a debugger, so you would use that on the host PC side (e.g. pass it to gdb).

The method of flashing the `zephyr.bin` file depends on the board. It looks like for the Carbon 96 you [use `dfu-util`](https://www.zephyrproject.org/doc/boards/arm/96b_carbon/doc/96b_carbon.html#flashing-zephyr-onto-96boards-carbon). You then press the Reset button to boot with the new image.